# HTML Mail Padding issue in Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook

[image]

I am facing a very annoying issue regarding HTML mails. My mail template is working absolutely fine with all browsers and it is showing perfectly fine in gmail, office mail (web). But with outlook client I am getting 4 pixel extra padding.

I have checked the compute section where I can see the image size which I have defined and actual size in mail are different.

Here I am attaching the problematic part screenshot for your reference.

Could you please help me on it.

---

### HTML Code

```
<table width="859" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td height="180"><img src="/sites/default/files/img/report_mail_header.jpg" alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="136"><img src="/sites/default/files/img/report_mail_title.jpg" alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#f9f9f9">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" height="58"><img src="/sites/default/files/img/box1.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="111" height="354"><img src="/sites/default/files/img/box4.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <table width="90%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0" align="center">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="font-size:18px;line-height:135%"><br><br>Details of the accounts that are part of our community of ****<br><br>Account status: <font color="#1f6d79">active or inactive institutions</font>
                                        <br>Details of the <font color="#83babc">institutions that are really reporting</font>
                                        <br>The details of the <font color="#1f6d79">accounts that entered to the platform the last month</font>
                                        <br>As you know, "*** **** ****" is an initiative to create value to our customers - Leading our team to gain differentiation and loyalty
                                        <br><strong><font color="#1f6d79">Best Regards,<br>**** ****</font></strong></font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td width="114" align="right"><img src="/sites/default/files/img/box2.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" height="132"><img src="/sites/default/files/img/box3.jpg" alt="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td height="120"><img src="/sites/default/files/img/report_mail_footer.jpg" alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You seem to have forgot to post the problematic full html code so we the problem and offer assistance.

Comment: And CSS if any. Please edit your question to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I have attached my html mail content. due privacy some names are stared out.